# Sending mail using Sendmail : DSesmtp setting

Tags: rhel, email, sendmail

Need some clarification on Mail Settings. We are managing around hundreds of applications. These applications runs on Linux based hosts and used to send mails to users based on user registration at site and other actions.

We have `Sendmail` configured on these Linux servers to relay mails to destination mailbox. The following setting is being used in `sendmail.cf` to forward mails to relay mail server.

```
        DSesmtp:xmail.example.com
```

This is fine for me. But on some servers , I can see only `sendmail` is running but the above settings is not enabled. But still mails are going through this server. 
I tried to  send mails to Yahoo and GMAIL accounts and mails are successfully getting delivered.

```
   Aug 31 03:36:12 vmprod sendmail[23396]: u7V7aCMr023396: from=<admin@vmprod.wiley.com>, size=534, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201608310736.u7V7aCee023393@vmprod.wiley.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, *relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]*
   Aug 31 03:36:12 vmprod sendmail[23393]: u7V7aCee023393: to=queszama@yahoo.in, ctladdr=admin (35014/10), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30220, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (u7V7aCMr023396 Message accepted for delivery)
   Aug 31 03:36:13 vmprod sendmail[23398]: STARTTLS=client, relay=mx-apac.mail.gm0.yahoodns.net., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=RC4-SHA, bits=128/128
   Aug 31 03:36:16 vmprod sendmail[23398]: u7V7aCMr023396: to=<queszama@yahoo.in>, ctladdr=<admin@vmprod.wiley.com> (35014/10), delay=00:00:04, xdelay=00:00:04, mailer=esmtp, pri=120534, *relay=mx-apac.mail.gm0.yahoodns.net*. [106.10.166.52], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (ok dirdel)
```

No `Postfix,Exim` running on this host

```
  -bash-4.1$ ps -ef | grep postifx
  essadmin  8974 20942  0 06:20 pts/4    00:00:00 grep postifx
  -bash-4.1$ ps -ef | grep exim
   essadmin  8982 20942  0 06:20 pts/4    00:00:00 grep exim
```

`/etc/resolv.conf` is pointing to a valid DNS server .

```
   $ cat /etc/redhat-release
   Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.3 (Santiago)
```

I am confused how mails are getting delivered since `SMARTHOST` is not configured . Any pointers ?

Comment: What is reported by the following test commands execured by root? `echo '$S' | sendmail -bt` `sendmail -bv queszama@yahoo.in`

Comment: Shows the following                                                                          `sudo $ echo '$S' | sendmail -bt sendmail -bv queszama@yahoo.in
ADDRESS TEST MODE (ruleset 3 NOT automatically invoked)
Enter <ruleset> <address>`
>

Answer (score -1):

The system might be using an alternative to sendmail, like postfix or exim.

Check with the following command (as root):

```
netstat --tcp -lnp | grep :25
```

You will get something like:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1464/master
tcp        0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1464/master
```

Then check who this is with:

```
ps -aef | grep 1464 # replace 1464 with your pid
```

I get the following for instance:

```
root      1464     1  0  2015 ?        00:01:35 /usr/lib/postfix/master -w
postfix   1468  1464  0  2015 ?        00:00:25 qmgr -l -t fifo -u
postfix  25106  1464  0 09:13 ?        00:00:00 pickup -l -t fifo -u
```

Comment: So exim is your "sendmail". Have you checked the exim configuration files then? Probably /etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf

Comment: $ ls /etc/exim
-bash-4.1$ sudo rpm -qa | grep exim
If no exim running , how come reading configuration file ?

Comment: "What does ps -aef | grep -i exim" say?

Comment: -bash-4.1$ ps -aef | grep -i exim
admin 10294 20942  0 06:34 pts/4    00:00:00 grep -i exim

Comment: So exim is not running (I got "exit" in your first comment was exim). Which operating system is it?